# Horizontal Pressure on a Curved Wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

[image]

Can someone please clarify why the horizontal pressure on the wall is 0.5 x $\gamma$ x $h^2$?

Is this because F = P x dA, and P pressure is $\rho$ x g x h.  Integrating P x dA gives you 1/2 x $\gamma$ x $h^2$